# Building 64bit Qt on 32bit Xp computer

Tags: c++, qt, 64-bit, qmake

I'm trying to build Qt in a shared 64 bit mode on my 32bit XP system.

I can configure the QMake and start the 64bit build.  The problem is that when the build starts, the first thing that happens in that the process builds ui, moc and rcc utility compilers in 64 bit mode, then tries to run them on my 32bit machine.

Does anyone know how to configure the build so that it does not build those compilers first?

Comment: Moc is requied to build a lot of classes in Qt, it has to build it and run it at some point.

Comment: My problem is not building moc.  32 bit version of moc.exe is part of the initial distribution.  My problem is that when I build the 64 bit version of Qt, the first think that happeans is that the build overwrites the 32 bit moc.exe with the 64 bit moc.exe.  Then, moc no longer runs on my  machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Qt support cross-compilation on Windows.

I suggest doing it the other way around, by using a 64bit machine (and a 64 bit version of Windows) to build the 64bit and 32bit versions.

Comment: That is a great idea if your IT department will let you.  However, our IT department has all the developers using XP-32 machines.  Same as the rest of the company.  To do it for us, I actually brought in my own machine from home which is a Win 7/64 machine to do it.

Comment: Hmm, if you need to do that but IT won't let you, then it sounds like you actually have an entirely different problem!

Comment: @photo_tom Perhaps use an Amazon [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) windows instance for 64 bit builds? Fully licensed 64bit windows server instances on demand could be part of your build solution.